# unable catch exception new capture emgu CV c#

Tags: emgucv, capture

I'm doing projects using camera IP source onvif, but i can't catch exception when initialization new capture camera :
[image]

I'm start app debug but System Suspended by code new Capture(source ovif) , can't show exception. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

try using "Exception" in catch statement.

```
try
{
  ....
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToSting());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your camera online and internet speed is enough to receive video? Try to decrease video resolution. Maybe you got same bug as I - https://github.com/emgucv/emgucv/issues/22

Comment: @lalithkumar, too low reputation to do that